# Can't read text file from assets with button click

Tags: android, assets, file-read

i've seen this question is common, but after searching i couldnt figure out the solution to my problem: the goal is to read a simple text file from assets when a button is clicked. I've followed this tutorial, adapted to my project, but when the button is clicked, nothing happens, although the file is in the right place. Here's the code and thanks in advance:

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button restart;
Button answers;
TextView ler;
TextView msg;

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
    ler=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ler);
    answers=(Button) findViewById(R.id.answers);
    answers.setOnClickListener(this);
    restart=(Button) findViewById(R.id.restartQuiz);
    restart.setOnClickListener(this);

    msg.setText("Correct Answers: " + QuizActivity.correct + "Wrong Answers: "
            + QuizActivity.wrong + " Your Final Score is " + QuizActivity.score);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == restart) {

        QuizActivity.score=0;
        QuizActivity.correct=0;
        QuizActivity.wrong=0;
        Intent a = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(a);
    }
    if(view==answers){
        String text="";
        try{
            InputStream is= getAssets().open("file.txt");
            int size=is.available();
            byte [] buffer=new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ler.setText(text);
    }
  }

 public void onBackPressed() {

  }
}
```

Comment: text is never assigned, isn't it? `text = new String(buffer, 0, size)` after `is.read` could help

Comment: @Blackbelt, well that didnt work either...i dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: does `file.txt` exist into `assets/` ? Was an exception thrown ?

Comment: @Blackbelt, i'm sorry, yes it did, thank you very much, i missed that line in the tutorial...:)

Comment: which line did you miss?

Comment: the line you provided...I posted the solution with a comment in that line. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is code may help you a class whose implementation is provided by
>   the Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources
>   and classes. Return an AssetManager instance for your application's
>   package.

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

 Button restart;
 Button answers;
 TextView ler;
 TextView msg;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
ler=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ler);
answers=(Button) findViewById(R.id.answers);
answers.setOnClickListener(this);
restart=(Button) findViewById(R.id.restartQuiz);
restart.setOnClickListener(this);

msg.setText("Correct Answers: " + QuizActivity.correct + "Wrong Answers: "
        + QuizActivity.wrong + " Your Final Score is " + QuizActivity.score);


}

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
 if (view == restart) {

    QuizActivity.score=0;
    QuizActivity.correct=0;
    QuizActivity.wrong=0;
    Intent a = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(a);
   }
   if(view==answers){
    String text="";
    try{
AssetManager text = myContext.getAssets();
    InputStream is = text.open("file.txt");
        InputStream is= getAssets().open("file.txt");
        int size=is.available();
        byte [] buffer=new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);

       text = new String(buffer, 0, size); //this line was missing

        is.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ler.setText(text);
  }
}

public void onBackPressed() {

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thaks to the tip of BlackBelt, this is the solution:

```
 public class ResultActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

 Button restart;
 Button answers;
 TextView ler;
 TextView msg;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
ler=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ler);
answers=(Button) findViewById(R.id.answers);
answers.setOnClickListener(this);
restart=(Button) findViewById(R.id.restartQuiz);
restart.setOnClickListener(this);

msg.setText("Correct Answers: " + QuizActivity.correct + "Wrong Answers: "
        + QuizActivity.wrong + " Your Final Score is " + QuizActivity.score);


}

 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
 if (view == restart) {

    QuizActivity.score=0;
    QuizActivity.correct=0;
    QuizActivity.wrong=0;
    Intent a = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(a);
   }
   if(view==answers){
    String text="";
    try{
        InputStream is= getAssets().open("file.txt");
        int size=is.available();
        byte [] buffer=new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);

       text = new String(buffer, 0, size); //this line was missing

        is.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ler.setText(text);
  }
}

public void onBackPressed() {

 }
}
```